# How to determine which sibling receieves the event?

Tags: c++, qt, inheritance

A QWidget Class is a parent of multiple QWidget siblings which overlap. When implementing the mousePressEvent just the most recent constructed child is recieving the event.
Is there a way that all siblings get the event?
Or even better a way to set which child is expected to be recieving it?

---

p.s. I'm assuming this is clear enough without providing sourcecode, especially since the minimal example would be quiet big anyway. If some one expects the code to be required anyway, leave a comment and I'll add it.

Comment: You can change the z-order with [`raise`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#raise), [`lower`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#lower) and  [`stackUnder`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#stackUnder) functions.

Comment: The complete example needed to demonstrate this problem is absolutely critical to provide the background necessary to answer the question, and should be no longer than 50 lines, probably half that, really.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use `QEvent::ignore()` function to mark an event as ignored in the widget. Doing so you will propagate it to the parent widget. According to Qt docs on `QEvent::ignore()` function:

> Clears the accept flag parameter of the event object, the equivalent
>   of calling setAccepted(false). Clearing the accept parameter indicates
>   that the event receiver does not want the event. Unwanted events might
>   be propagated to the parent widget.

Comment: I'll try it. But as I undersstand it, it will just skip that line of "generation" and not pass it to another sibling who might want it?!

Comment: If you have a widgets hierarchy the event first reaches the most low level widget and, if it's accepted, will not reach to other widgets. Otherwise, it will go up in the hierarchy until it's accepted.

Comment: Yeah but by saying "siblings" I mean they are onb the same level of hierachy. And my current problem is I don't know how to influence which of them recieves the event. the widgets geometry is overlapping and they are on the same level. I don't want to pass it through. I want to be able to controll which one recieves it, or make at least all of them recieve it.

Comment: If you are talking about mouse event, does it mean all your "siblings" are overlapping each other? If yes, then why GUI is designed in this way?

Comment: Yeah, thats what I'm talking about. Uhm, because I didn't know how to do it better? :x So my GUI design is actually the problem?

Comment: @Zaibis "the widgets geometry is overlapping and they are on the same level" This belongs in the question itself.

Comment: Is there a reason why all siblings need to get the same event? If they are overlapping, the co-ordinates will need to be adjusted and this seems like a lot of extra work.

Answer (score 0):

You should generate new event in callback method of each sibling class.

```
void QWidgetChild::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    // Act
    // Pass to parent
    QWidget::mousePressEvent(event);

   // Generate new event for objects of sibling classes
   // How?
}
```

See [postEvent](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qcoreapplication.html#postEvent) documentation.

Comment: I had tryed this allready after reading other answers on this. Sadly it had no effect on the behavior that makes me trouble. `QWidget::mousePressEvent(event);` just appeared to me to pass the event through in hierachy. Not keeping it on the same level for other siblings.